# Oracle - how to update a unique row based on MAX effective date which is part of the unique index

Tags: oracle

Oracle - Say you have a table that has a unique key on name, ssn and effective date.  The effective date makes it unique.  What is the best way to update a current indicator to show inactive for the rows with dates less than the max effective date?  I can't really wrap my head around it since there are multiple rows with the same name and ssn combinations.  I haven't been able to find this scenario on here for Oracle and I'm having developer's block.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"All name/ssn having a max effective date earlier than this time yesterday:"

```
SELECT name, ssn
FROM t
GROUP BY name, ssn
HAVING MAX(eff_date) < SYSDATE - 1
```

Oracle supports multi column in, so

```
UPDATE t
SET current_indicator = 'inactive'
WHERE (name,ssn,eff_date) IN (
  SELECT name, ssn, max(eff_date)
  FROM t
  GROUP BY name, ssn
  HAVING MAX(eff_date) < SYSDATE - 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement using an analytic function to identify the rows to update and then merge on the `ROWID` pseudo-column so that Oracle can efficiently identify the rows to update (without having to perform an expensive self-join by comparing the values):

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT rid,
         max_eff_date
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROWID AS rid,
           effective_date,
           status,
           MAX( effective_date ) OVER ( PARTITION BY name, ssn ) AS max_eff_date
    FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE ( effective_date < max_eff_date AND status <> 'inactive' )
  OR    ( effective_date = max_eff_date AND status <> 'active' )

) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.rid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET status = CASE
               WHEN src.max_eff_date = dst.effective_date 
               THEN 'active'
               ELSE 'inactive'
               END;
```

So, for some sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( name, ssn, effective_date, status ) AS
SELECT 'aaa', 1, DATE '2020-01-01', 'inactive' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaa', 1, DATE '2020-01-02', 'inactive' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaa', 1, DATE '2020-01-03', 'inactive' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bbb', 2, DATE '2020-01-01', 'active'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bbb', 2, DATE '2020-01-02', 'inactive' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bbb', 3, DATE '2020-01-01', 'inactive' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bbb', 3, DATE '2020-01-03', 'active'   FROM DUAL;
```

The query only updates the 3 rows that need changing and:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> NAME | SSN | EFFECTIVE_DATE | STATUS  
> :--- | --: | :------------- | :-------
> aaa  |   1 | 01-JAN-20      | inactive
> aaa  |   1 | 02-JAN-20      | inactive
> aaa  |   1 | 03-JAN-20      | active  
> bbb  |   2 | 01-JAN-20      | inactive
> bbb  |   2 | 02-JAN-20      | active  
> bbb  |   3 | 01-JAN-20      | inactive
> bbb  |   3 | 03-JAN-20      | active
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=48ca2bb976b77dd96358d8a4013da177)*